# MYSQL and PHP fewer API calls

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a api query

```
select id, name, info1, info2 from Account
```

what i want to know ... is there a way to get all the unique names without having to requery

```
select distinct name from account
```

im trying to use as little of the api calls as possible?

For example, table named account is as follows

```
name    number
charles 1
mary    2
charles 3
mary    4
```

im trying to

```
select name,number from account
```

is there a way to

```
select name where name=charles from account
```

without having to requery the api?

Comment: what about `distinct` ? or `groupby` ?

Comment: i think my question wasnt clear. ill re edit the main post.

Comment: Why are you selecting `name` when you know `name`? Do you mean to select all the numbers that "charles" has?